# Create 5 columns of equal height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I got a couple of columns created with bootstrap for a footer. Each column has some info in them (i.e: address, links etc). But a column with more information in it than the other, will be longer, so all the columns are not evenly lined out. How can I fix this?

My footer:

```
<div class="row row-centered">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-centered col-centered">
                            <!-- Address -->
                                <div class="" style="padding-right:0">
                                    <div class="contact-item">
                                        <div class="ci-icon">
                                            <i class="fa fa-building-o"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ci-title font-alt">
                                            Markten
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ci-text">
                                            Website B.V.<br>
                                            Overkampsweg 16a<br>
                                            8102 PH Raalte
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- End Address -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-centered">
                            <!-- Address -->
                                <div class="" style="padding-right:0">
                                    <div class="contact-item">
                                        <div class="ci-icon">
                                            <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ci-title font-alt">
                                            Producten
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ci-text">
                                            <a href="http://www.website.nl/filtering.html">Filtering</a><br>
                                            <a href="http://www.website.nl/toebehoren.html">Toebehoren</a><br>
                                            <a href="http://wwww.website.nl/zacht.html">Zacht</a>
                                            <a href="http://www.website.nl/hard.html">Hard</a>
                                            <a href="http://www.website.nl/technische-gegevens.html">Technische gegevens</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- End Address -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-centered">
                            <!-- Address -->
                                <div class="" style="padding-right:0">
                                    <div class="contact-item">
                                        <div class="ci-icon">
                                            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ci-title font-alt">
                                            Diensten
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ci-text">
                                            Website B.V.<br>
                                            Overkampsweg 16a<br>
                                            8102 PH Raalte
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- End Address -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-centered">
                            <!-- Address -->
                                <div class="" style="padding-right:0">
                                    <div class="contact-item">
                                        <div class="ci-icon">
                                            <i class="fa fa-external-link"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ci-title font-alt">
                                            Links
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ci-text">
                                            Link 1<br>
                                            Link 2<br>
                                            Link 3
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- End Address -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-centered">
                            <!-- Address -->
                                <div class="" style="padding-right:0">
                                    <div class="contact-item">
                                        <div class="ci-icon">
                                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ci-title font-alt">
                                            Adresgegevens
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ci-text">
                                            Website B.V.<br>
                                            Overkampsweg 16a<br>
                                            8102 PH Raalte
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- End Address -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

With css:

```
/* centered columns styles */
.row-centered {
    text-align:center;
}
.col-centered {
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
    /* reset the text-align */
    text-align:left;
    /* inline-block space fix */
    margin-right:-4px;
}

.row-centered {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

Jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/L7L8dryd/

Comment: Did you try searching for a solution here on stackoverflow? This question has already been answered multiple times. For example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19695851/1765877) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23288066/1765877).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work well for me, hope it will resolve your issue.

Change this class and add table-cell as display value.

```
.col-centered{
 display:table-cell; 
}
```

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: I checked again, please try and apply "equal_height" class to all the divs.
I have updated the code

Comment: I did add equal_height as a class name to all divs But still it doesn't work for me. Maybe I have to add that these are 5 columns. So I am using offset 1. Maybe that doesn't work with your solution?

Comment: No No, it will work fine, sorry I missed a (dot.) in the script. please use this updated code.. it'll work. :)

Comment: I added everything you posted, but still this is the footer: https://gyazo.com/fe17c9865ef266335ac4b3b8395686cb

This is one colum block for example: https://gyazo.com/aee365b82eb84996bdc07bfc85f690c3

Comment: can i see the URL? I can debug and tell you the exact fix after seeing

Comment: Can I message you somewhere so that the link is not public here on stackoverflow?

Comment: Change this class and add table-cell as display value.

.col-centered{
      display:table-cell;
}

Comment: great! please vote ^ too :)

Comment: My reputation is too low, I will when I have enough

Answer (score 0):

You can use only bootstrap to do this, [see this example at bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/).

Comment: This did not work for me in Firefox unfortunately. I only have to add that class? No CSS?

Comment: Oh yes, there is a css, it is not a default yet (it will in bootstrap4) , here is the css link, used in bootstrap example: http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/equal-height-columns.css i hope it helps

Comment: Thank you,but this stacks the columns on top of eachother :P

Comment: Hmmmm, so, see if this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32867594/how-can-i-place-column-content-on-the-bottom/32868004#32868004 just change from "bottom" to "middle" or you can provide us a fiddle to help

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the padding-right: 0px; ? It was already in the template so maybe it's best not to remove it

Comment: I added a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L7L8dryd/

Comment: See if is what you want, https://jsfiddle.net/L7L8dryd/1/ if not, what else you need

Comment: I see it still floats to the right when i resize the screen. I want it to stay centered, and stack upon eachother when resizing it to phone size.